# Python Pandas Combined Date and Hour Into One Column and plot using lineplot

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, jupyter

I have my data as below. I need to combine this date and hour into a single column and I need to plot a line plot for year 2015 and its corresponding hours.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdlM0.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi thank you. The suggestion given by @Chris A worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the following to combine your `MultiIndex` into a single `DatetimeIndex`:

```
df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df.index.get_level_values(0) ) +
             pd.to_timedelta(df.index.get_level_values(1), unit='H'),
             inplace=True)
```

From the data you provided, there appears to be gaps, for example there is no 'msg_count' value at *2015-01-01 09:00*.

To fix this you can [`DataFrame.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with [`pandas.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html) and fill missing entries with `0`

```
new_idx = pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max(), freq='H')

df.reindex(new_idx, fill_value=0, inplace=True)
```

To plot 2015 data only use:

```
df[df.index.year == 2015].plot()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new column that contains the date in datetime format, and then use the [matplotlib.pyplot.plot_date](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot_date.html) function to plot it.

```
import datetime as dt

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2018-12-12', '2018-12-12', '2018-12-13'], 'hour': [22, 23, 0], 'msg_count': [10, 20, 30]})

df['datetime'] = df.apply(
    lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x['date'], '%Y-%m-%d')
    + dt.timedelta(hours=x['hour']),
    axis=1)

plt.plot_date(df['datetime'], df['msg_count'])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the code snippet. I tried the same, but getting the below error. "AttributeError: ("'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'datetime'", 'occurred at index (2014-12-31, 23)')"

Comment: It looks like the DataFrame you have was grouped by `date` and `hour`, am I correct? Then the problem you have is that `date` and `hour` are part of the index. You should do a `df = df.reset_index()` before running the apply part and the plot part.